# How to echo the string"off" in DOS

Tags: batch-file, dos

AS we know ,we can echo off ,but we can`t echo an "off",is there anything like Data Link Escape Character can help me to echo an off ???

I have tried echo /off   echo %off   echo "off".But they aren`t what i need ?

Comment: IIRC, try something like `echo.off`.

Comment: See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08e80dec-f915-49ab-ac76-c0c5e33bbe75/echo-command-in-cmdexe?forum=ITCG

Answer (score 4):

You can use `echo(` for any content instead of `echo`.

It can be used also for empty lines and other content like
`\..\..\..\..\windows\system32.calc`

So this works

```
echo(
echo(\..\..\..\..\windows\system32.calc
echo(off
echo(/?
```

`echo.` isn't the best choice, as it fails with some contents

```
echo.\..\..\..\..\windows\system32.calc
```

Even a simple `echo.` fails when a file `echo` exists (without extension).
And `echo.` is ~10 times slower than `echo` or `echo(`

For more infos [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554#p4554)

Comment: If you do not wish to see the **echo off** being echoed, put an @ sign in front of the echo